# Rails: Cookie overflow with omniauth twitter sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, devise, omniauth

I am using omniauth to let people sign up/sign in with Facebook and its working well ! But I wanted to add the omniauth-twitter gem to let them connect with Twitter.

I followed the same steps than when I set up the Facebook connect: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

But when I signing up/in I get the following error:

```
ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow in OmniauthCallbacksController#twitter
```

at the following URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=HRjON8J4bj9EcbjiELHcpHmSXo0cPd0wCHyuWG8ATZU&oauth_verifier=ZiZb1FAKZmNML1gVu5RKBLEGzbeAPPzC80QCpPDGU
```

I tried different things suggested on similar posts but none of these worked :(

Here is my configuration:

**omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb** => app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
def twitter
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.find_for_twitter_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "twitter") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.twitter_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
```

**user.rb** => app/models/user.rb

```
def self.find_for_twitter_oauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
  end
end

def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.twitter_data"] && session["devise.twitter_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end
```

**devise.rb** => app/config/initializers/devise.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :twitter, "KEY, "KEYPASSWORD
end
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: You put `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` which is a huge hash into session. What more answer do you need?

Comment: Pro tip: cut just the parts you NEED and put those in session.

Comment: My knowledge of code is very limited, as I started to learn code from scratch month ago, so I don't really now what this hash means. I just put it because I had it with my omniauth model for facebook authentification and it worked - What do you mean by it's a huge hash ? is it unnecessary ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Michael says in the comments, you're storing a large hash in the session and it's too big (you're using the default `CookieStore` and cookies can only contain 4KB of data).  That hash provided by omniauth has all the data returned by twitter, which can be quite a lot.  For example, see the README: https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter#authentication-hash

If the code in your question is all the code relating to twitter login, then it looks like you only need to keep the email in the session as that is all that is used by your `new_with_session` code.  So your line in the `else` in `twitter` which is:

```
session["devise.twitter_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
```

could be something like:

```
session["devise.twitter_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].select { |k, v| k == "email" }
```

*However* the major flaw with this is that twitter doesn't return an email address for a user, so data["email"] will always be `nil` in `new_with_session` anyway!  So it's pointless keeping anything in the session if you are only later interested in the email which is never returned by twitter.  Perhaps you instead want to retrieve a name to help prefill the registration form instead of the email address.  In this case, you could just keep that in the hash from omniauth.  If you want to keep a few things in the hash, then instead of selecting them all to put in the session, you could do something like:

```
session["devise.twitter_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].delete_if("extra")
```

which will remove the "extra" nested hash which could help everything else to fit in the session.

For a complete solution you'll have to consider messy situations like dealing with people who have signed in with Facebook and then come and sign in with Twitter and want to use the same email address and merge with their existing account on your system.

In any case, note that if you are using Rails 3 then the session cookie is not encrypted so the user or anyone with access to their computer could read the contents of the cookie with whatever data from twitter you end up keeping in there.  If you're using Rails 4, then the cookie should be encrypted to protect against that.

Comment: Shouldn't the second code example - to delete the extra block in the hash - be as follows: `session["devise.twitter_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].delete_if{|key, value| key == "extra"}`